# Prepositional phrasing using "at"

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, phrasal-verbs

> The rate we are going at, we won't be able to make it.

Does the "at" in the end make the sentence incorrect?

I'm confused whether I can use the "at" or not.

Comment: "at" is not at the end of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

This topic is hotly contested even among native speakers. Everyone agrees this is valid:

> At the rate we are going, ...

But not everyone agrees this is valid, even though it obviously means the same thing:

> The rate we are going at, ...

Those who don’t believe it is valid refer to a prohibition on “dangling prepositions”, and they will go out of their way to rearrange sentences to avoid it.

The rest of us accept that people do actually speak and write this way, at least informally, and regard the alleged prohibition as a case of hypercorrection.

If your teacher considers it invalid, accept that and comply to pass the test. But you’ll hear it in the real world either way.

Comment: Thanks! So that means it's fine at least in spoken informal speech?

Comment: @RefayeturRezaArnab I’m firmly in the camp that says it’s okay. Even those who don’t like it will understand you.

Comment: at the rate we are going is completely valid. In writing it would probably be at the beginning, in speech, at the end.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit controversial and opinions vary depending on the school of thinking you believe **in**. People who are fans of descriptive grammar believe that grammar should follow the actual usage patterns you hear in your day to day life. Therefore, a structure like the one you mentioned is valid as native speakers use it without batting an eye. On the other hand, some people with a more conservative mindset (prescriptive grammarians) contest the usage of this structure because previous people didn't use it in their writing and it is not functionally needed.

Answer (score -1):

The clause makes the sentence incomplete as written, and would need a word like "with" to make it complete:

"With the rate we are going at"

Many English speakers would prefer the construction "at the rate we are going" and that clause would make the sentence complete.